# UUID not working with JOOQ and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Whenever I try to set or retrieve a field of UUID type, I get the following error from JOOQ: "Not supported by dialect : Type class java.util.UUID is not supported in dialect null"

Everything else works great and as far as I can tell the dialect is properly set to Postgres.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you show a bit of your code? It's hard to guess things at this stage of your question :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what code would be useful.  I have a database with type UUID.  The simplest thing that triggers it is TABLE.FIELD.cast(UUID.class).  I also see this when trying to do a factory.update() or .getValue from a record set.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm on Postgres 9.3 and Jooq 2.6.4.

Answer (score 3):

You're using jOOQ 2.6.4. `java.util.UUID` types are only supported from jOOQ 3.0 onwards:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1624
- http://www.jooq.org/notes#3.0.0

But while you're at it, you might want to upgrade to the very latest version (which is 3.4.1, at the time I have provided this answer)